How can i make a login feature in my Angular 16 app to Login using cognito username and password
I am creating an angular 16 app . i have been given a username and password that belongs to a cognito user pool now i want to create a Login page in my app that should authenticate and log in such users .
I am not able to find relevant solutions for Angular 16
I have tried some blogs but all of them are giving some error in the end

You can use the "amazon-cognito-identity-js" plugin the latest version of it to further authenticate the user based on their credentials. Here is the sample for the same:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/authentication.html
Thanks
